# How to implement a class simulating the array in c++

Tags: c++, class

I have been given a .h file, based on which I need to implement a class that simulates some functions of the array in c++.
There are two given instance variables in the .h file

```
int *array;             /* The dynamic array holding the elements */
int nElements;          /* The number of elements in the array    */
```

I tried the following as the class constructor (though I know it won't work before I did so):

```
IntArray::IntArray(int n)
{
array = new IntArray[n];
nElements = n;
}
```

What should I write to make the constructor work?

This is the original .h file for reference.
[1]: https://mega.nz/file/P0FVkBCQ#ME3fK_U7-H8iVHLMC7tyCCKxF-xbCMphEaERunZ-y9c

Answer (score -1):

The variable `array` is a pointer to `int`, so you should allocate an array of `int`.

```cpp
IntArray::IntArray(int n)
{
    array = new int[n];
    nElements = n;
}
```